# c++ how to convert already created object to unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a `get` function which returns an object of type `MyClass` called `myObject`:

```
MyClass myObject = something.get(id);
```

I want to convert `myObject` to `unique_ptr`, how to do it?

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(&myObject); // Is this correct?
```

Comment: Think about what happens when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope and it tries to `delete` the contained pointer, a pointer which doesn't point to something allocated with `new`.

Comment: @GeorgeAl so you mean `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(myObject);`?

Comment: Certainly, not. unique_ptr is for objects allocated in heap

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>( new MyClass(myObject) );` ?

Comment: A bigger and more important question is *why* do you want to create a `unique_ptr` here? What is the use-case? What is the *actual* problem you try to solve? [Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm using a function which accepts unique_ptr.

Comment: @GeorgeAl what if the copy constructor is deleted?

Comment: @user3828398, then the line you show in your example implies move construction, and `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>( new MyClass( std::move(myObject) ) );`

Comment: @GeorgeAl it's copy assignment operator.

Comment: @user3828398, the object is declared at that point so its copy construction (if the constructor is declared public and implemented)

Comment: A function that takes a `unique_ptr` takes ownership of the object - ie. the caller no longer owns it. Is that needed for this function ? If not, can it be modified to take a reference instead ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
MyClass myObject = something.get(id);
```

Implies either copy or move construction.

If your copy constructor is defined and declared public try the following

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> my_p_obj( new MyClass(myObject) );
```

Where you create a new object and initialize it by copying.

Otherwise the object in your example is initialized through move construction

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> my_p_obj( new MyClass( std::move(myObject) ) );
```

> what's wrong with std::unique_ptr(&myObject);

`myObject` is an object in the local scope which will be destroyed when the function it lies in reaches the end (`}`). If you call the destructor twice (one from the compiler, the second from `unique_ptr`) you get undefined behaviour

Edit : As cleared up in the comments,  you could make use of `auto my_p_obj = std::make_unique<MyClass>(myObject)` which does the same thing. – **Thanks, Andreas H.**

Comment: Or you could make use of `auto my_p_obj = std::make_unique<MyClass>(myObject)` which does basically the same thing as `std::unique_ptr<MyClass> my_p_obj(new MyClass(myObject))`.

Comment: @AndreasH., I wasn't sure if it was possible to make `unique_ptr` through a `make_unique` and a copy constructor. Thanks for clearing that up. I added an edit on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you would initialize it with the reference, it would give problems when you get out of scope. One possibility:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct MyClass
{
};

int main()
{
   MyClass myObject;
   std::unique_ptr<MyClass>( new MyClass(myObject) ); 
}
```

Comment: what if the copy constructor is deleted?

Comment: @user3828398 You can `std::move` it?

Comment: what's wrong with `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(&myObject);`?